# How to find out SQL Server Enterprise 2012 expiration date?

Tags: sql-server, database, sql-server-2012

I have SQL Server Enterprise Edition 64-bit that installed on VMplayer,

```
Version:   11.0.3128.0    
Product LVL:  SP1
```

Upon installed, there is no documents indicates how long this license will last.

Anyone can tell me a way to find out the expiration date?

Comment: First please post output of select @@Version. Enterprise edition has no limitation with number of days you can use lifelong Enterprise evaluation edition has limitations for 180 days. And query which Raman posted will give you wrong information for Enterprise edition

Answer (score 2):

Use below command to find the details

```
SELECT  create_date AS 'SQL Server Installed Date',
    Expiry_date AS 'SQL Server Expiry Date',
    DATEDIFF(dd,create_date, GETDATE()) 'No_of_Days_Used',
    ABS(DATEDIFF(dd,expiry_date,GETDATE())) 'No_Of_Days_Left'
 FROM
   (SELECT sp.create_date,
    DATEADD(dd, 180, sp.create_date) AS Expiry_date
    FROM   sys.server_principals sp
    WHERE  sp.name = 'NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM') as exp_date_tbs
```